# How to change value of element in a event that included by other event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem. How to solve this?
when I click on 'test'. 'b' would be shown. then I click on 'b'. it will change the value of 'a'. I need the value of a that included by 'container' not other values in other elements is are as same as class name 'container'. how? help me.

```
<head>
<style>
    #test {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
    }
    .c {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        color: red;
        background: black;
    }

    .b {
        display: none;
        color: black;
        background: blueviolet;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<div>
<div class="container"><div id="test"></div><div class="c">hello</div></div> 
<div class="b"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#test').on('click',function name(params) {
    $('.b').show();
    var a = $(this).parent().find('.c').html();
    $('.b').click(function name(params) {
        // how to change value of a?
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem Please explain what the problem is.

Comment: Because of the way javascript clojures work, you can just... change it. Inside the .click callback, literally just write `test = 'newvalue';`

Comment: b.click(function(){test = 'a';)}. i wrote it but doesnt have a change

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have a click within a click but you would want to move `b.click` out of `a.click`. Then you need to declare your variable outside of `a.click` otherwise `b.click` will never reach it.

So, declare test with no value, then change the value of test within each click.

```js
var a;
$('#test').on('click', function name(params) {
  $('.b').show();
  a = $(this).parent().find('.c').html('toBeginning');

});
$('.b').click(function name(params) {
  a = $('.container').find('.c').html('changed')
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  background: black;
}

.b {
  display: none;
  color: black;
  background: blueviolet;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="test">Test</div>
    <div class="c">hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no. this will be change all values of class "some-class" when it isn't in parents of some-class. I only want to change value of parent of some-class

Comment: Check my updated snippet. You have to bring out the variable `a` if you want to be able to change it within the `b` click.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you looking this?**

```js
var a = '';
$('#test').on('click',function name(params) {
    $('.b').show();
    if(!a) {
      a = $(this).parent().find('.c').html();
    }
    $(this).parent().find('.c').html(a);
});

$('.b').click(function name(params) {
   // how to change value of a?
   $('.container .c').html('changed value');
});
```

```css
#test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
.c {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: red;
    background: black;
}

.b {
    display: none;
    color: black;
    background: blueviolet;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div class="c">hello</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```